# Do something when a user comes back to NSViewController

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I came from iOS world where `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidDisappear` was useful to track when a user switched to another view or came back from it.

What is the proper way to track when a view associated with NSViewController become "active" (a user switched from another window with a view to this one)?

I am looking for some callback/a method to override to learn about a user transition back to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa on macOS supports [viewDidAppear()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434455-viewdidappear) et al. since 10.10. It works the same as iOS.

However if you are targeting an earlier macOS version, the callbacks won't work. In which case, you can approximate the behaviour but it's a bit tricky.

You can follow things at the window level with [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate)

Particularly the callbacks `windowDidBecomeKey` and `windowDidResignKey`. These can be used to notify your NSViewControllers.

You also have some useful methods on NSView, especially [viewWillMove(toWindow:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483415-viewwillmove).